# cpprestsdk server POST read failure

Tags: c++, cpprest-sdk

I sent a json POST with curl, but I can't read it from the server. What is the problem?

```
void Handler::handle_post(http_request request){
    std::cout << request.to_string() << std::endl;
    auto j = json::value::object();
    request.extract_json().then([&j](pplx::task<json::value> task) {
    try{
        auto const & jvalue = task.get();
        for (auto const & e : jvalue.as_array())
        {
            if (e.is_string())
            {
                auto key = e.as_string();
                std::cout << key << std::endl;
            }
         }
    }
    catch (http_exception const & e)
        {
            std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;
        }
    }).wait();
    request.reply(status_codes::OK);
}
```

curl :

`curl -d '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:10022`

server request:

[image]

If there is insufficient information, I will show you the full code.